# Keras Error: could not broadcast input array from shape (300,300,3) into shape (300,300)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have following code that should train a keras model with a bunch of pictures that are either dummy_images or product_images that produces the Error `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (300,300,3) into shape (300,300)`:

```
# import packages
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import sklearn
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
import cv2
import imageio
from skimage import io

# Defining Filepath
dummyPath = os.path.join('data', 'train', 'dummy')
productPath = os.path.join('data', 'train', 'product')
dummy, product = os.listdir(dummyPath), os.listdir(productPath)

# Loading the images
print("loading images")
images = []
label = []
for i in dummy:
    image = imageio.imread(os.path.join(dummyPath, i))
    images.append(image)
    label.append(0)  # for dummy images

for i in product:
    image = imageio.imread(os.path.join(productPath, i))
    images.append(image)
    label.append(1)  # for product images

# resizing all images
print("resizing images")
for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i] = cv2.resize(images[i], (300, 300))

# converting images to arrays
print("converting images to np-arrays")
images = np.array(images, dtype='object')
label = np.array(label)

# Defining the hyperparameters
print("Defining Parameters")
filters = 10
filtersize = (5, 5)
epochs = 5
batchsize = 128
input_shape = (300, 300, 3)

# Converting the target variable to the required size
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
label = to_categorical(label)

# Defining the model
print("Defining the model")
model = Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(filters, filtersize, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid',
                                            data_format='channels_last', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_dim=50, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(images, label, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batchsize, validation_split=0.3)

model.summary()
```

The error is in the line (or its arguments):

`images = np.array(images, dtype='object')`

I tried to change `"images[i] = cv2.resize(images[i], (300, 300))"` to `"images[i] = cv2.resize(images[i], (300, 300, 3))"` but it throws the error that this parameter would just take two arguments, not three.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your images using numpy:

```
for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i] = np.resize(images[i], (300, 300, 3))
```